# Looking for assistance in identifying the similarity between news articles using cosine-similarity

Tags: vector, data-mining, cosine-similarity

TL;DR i'm currently creating a cross-platform mobile news aggregator, which will identify news articles from different publishers, but about the same topic, e.g. a celebrity passes away.

I believe I found an appropriate journal that can guide me through the steps 'Document Clustering with grouping and chaining algorithms'.
(https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I05-1025.pdf)

However many of the steps are confusing me such as:

1) Document clustering

2) Grouping and chaining algorithms

3) Understanding equations such as the one below that I'll need to compute.

[image]

Any help on the matter, or a brief description of the steps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

I'm also interested in any experts in this field, and would love to use your knowledge as qualitative evidence for my project. If you'd be be up for it please DM, or drop a comment. Thanks again!

Comment: This is far, far too broad for SO.  You might want to check out one of the other network sites (LInguistics?  CS?) for help in understanding the conceptual issues you're stuck on.  https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @Jason. I see you have expertise with Xamarin. Was wondering if you could help me fill-out a questionnaire that will provide qualitative justification for my project? Will take around 5-10 minutes.